# Why is RemoveSplash is no longer a member of CMainFrame?

Tags: c++, mfc

This code worked under Visual C++ 6.0:

```
BOOL CSplashWnd::PreTranslateAppMessage(MSG *pMsg)
{
    if (c_pSplashWnd == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    // If we get a keyboard or mouse message, hide the splash screen.
    if ((pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)       ||
        (pMsg->message == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)    ||
        (pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)   ||
        (pMsg->message == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)   ||
        (pMsg->message == WM_MBUTTONDOWN)   ||
        (pMsg->message == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN) ||
        (pMsg->message == WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN) ||
        (pMsg->message == WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN))
    {
    // let main frame window remove the splash screen so timer is killed &
    // Tip-of-the-Day is displayed (if appropriate)
    CMainFrame *pWnd = (CMainFrame *) AfxGetMainWnd();
    pWnd->RemoveSplash();

        return TRUE;    // message handled here
    }

    return FALSE;   // message not handled
}
```

Now in Visual Studio 2017 I get this error message:

> error C2039: 'RemoveSplash': is not a member of 'CMainFrame'

When I search for RemoveSplash in MSDN, I get no hits...

Was this ever a part of CMainFrame or CFrameWnd?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is "Why...?" Well, you'd have to ask someone at Microsoft and I doubt that they would know. You are asking about a product (6.0) that was released in 1998.  19 years ago. Many changes since then. Better C++ standards conformity, Unicode capable OSes, etc.

I've been programming MFC since 1995. I don't remember a built in splash window in MFC. Someone else added such a member to the CMainFrame class since it is not a part of MFC. It is derived probably from CFrameWnd or CMDIFrameWnd. Go look at MainFrm.h in your old VC++ project.

Answer (score 9):

`CMainFrame` was never part of MFC, but rather the default name of the frame window that the VS wizard generated for you. In other words, this was custom code.

Comment: So, if this is true, it would seem to indicate that @zett42 should not have edited my post to remove the VisualStudio tag and replace it with an mfc tag...

Comment: @ToddHoatson: The edit was correct. This has nothing to do with Visual Studio, other than MFC being a library deployed with Visual Studio. The issue is in *your* code, which we have no access to.

Comment: @IInspectable, are you saying that Eyal Cinamon is incorrect in his assessment that "CMainFrame was never part of MFC, but rather... VS wizard generated..."???  Even if you are correct, when you say MFC is a "library deployed with Visual Studio", then that makes it part of the VS product, does it not?

Comment: @ToddHoatson: I don't disagree with the gist of this answer. Still, the code could be wizard-generated, or simply written by a developer. There is no need to ever use a wizard to write MFC code, although few developers understand MFC well enough, to write MFC code without the support of an IDE. At any rate, the question is unrelated to Visual Studio, or its MFC wizards. Note in particular, that you do not need a wizard to compile wizard-generated code. The question asks about a customer-implemented class (whichever way it was initially created), without providing details about it.